# How to fix loops so that all scraped data gets appended to their lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, web-scraping

The script I have is to scrape the NHL-API, it is supposed to scrape all games in a season ranging from 2017020001 - 2017021271. I just finished up with it and realised that only the last game gets appended to each respective list. So in my case only game 2017021271 and not the rest 1270 games before it.

My code looks like this, what have I done terribly wrong?

I know it has to do with my borderline retarded looping, but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you for understanding!

```
#Importing Libraries 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

#Create Empty lists
player_id = {}
goalie_id = {}

person = []
position = []
skaterstats = []

goalie_person=[]
goalie_position=[]
goalie_stats=[]

team = []
team_goals = []
matchid = []

#Connect to NHL-API
for game_id in range(2017020001, 2017020100, 1):
    url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{}/feed/live'.format(game_id)
    r = requests.get(url)
    game_data = r.json()

#Get Keys for Players/Goalies
for homeaway in ['home','away']:
    player_dict = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('skaters')
    player_id[homeaway] = player_dict

for homeaway in ['home','away']:
    goalie_dict = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('goalies')
    goalie_id[homeaway] = goalie_dict 

#Get PlayerStats/TeamStats
for homeaway in player_id:
    for playerID in player_id[homeaway]:
    play_dict_teamname = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
    play_dict_teamgoals = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('teamStats').get('teamSkaterStats').get('goals')                
    play_dict_gameid = game_data.get('gamePk')

    play_dict_person = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('person')
    play_dict_position = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('position')
    play_dict_skaterstats = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('stats').get('skaterStats')

     #Append TeamStats to Empty list
    team.append(play_dict_teamname)
    team_goals.append(play_dict_teamgoals)
    matchid.append(play_dict_gameid)

    #Append PlayerStats to Empty list
    person.append(play_dict_person)
    position.append(play_dict_position)
    if play_dict_skaterstats: 
        skaterstats.append(play_dict_skaterstats)
    if not play_dict_skaterstats:
        play_dict_skaterstats = {}
        play_dict_skaterstats['timeOnIce'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['assists'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['goals'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['shots'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['hits'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['powerPlayGoals'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['powerPlayAssists'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['penaltyMinutes'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['faceOffPct'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['faceOffWins'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['faceoffTaken'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['takeaways'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['giveaways'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['shortHandedGoals'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['shortHandedAssists'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['blocked'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['plusMinus'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['evenTimeOnIce'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['powerPlayTimeOnIce'] = None
        play_dict_skaterstats['shortHandedTimeOnIce'] = None

skaterstats.append(play_dict_skaterstats)

#Get GoalieStats
for homeaway in goalie_id:
    for goalieID in goalie_id[homeaway]:
    play_dict_teamname = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
    play_dict_teamgoals = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('teamStats').get('teamSkaterStats').get('goals')                
    play_dict_gameid = game_data.get('gamePk')

    goalie_dict_person = play_dict_person = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(goalieID)).get('person')
    goalie_dict_position = play_dict_person = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(goalieID)).get('position')
    goalie_dict_stats = play_dict_person = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(goalieID)).get('stats').get('goalieStats')

    #Append GoalieStats to Empty list
    goalie_person.append(goalie_dict_person)
    goalie_position.append(goalie_dict_position)
    if goalie_dict_stats: 
        goalie_stats.append(goalie_dict_stats)

    #Append TeamStats to Empty list
    team.append(play_dict_teamname)
    team_goals.append(play_dict_teamgoals)
    matchid.append(play_dict_gameid)

#Create DataFrames for all lists
df_person = pd.DataFrame(person)
df_position = pd.DataFrame(position)
df_skaterstats = pd.DataFrame(skaterstats)

df_team = pd.DataFrame(team)
df_teamgoals = pd.DataFrame(team_goals)
df_gameID = pd.DataFrame(matchid)

df_goalie_per = pd.DataFrame(goalie_person)
df_goalie_pos = pd.DataFrame(goalie_position)
df_goalie_stats = pd.DataFrame(goalie_stats)
```

Comment: Please reformat the code in your question, Python needs proper indentation.

Comment: And please cut the example down to the least amount of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have done this in notebook so this is exacly how it is intended there, checked before posted. Sorry for not being able to be more helpful

Comment: @mkrieger1 This whole code is the problem as far as I know, perhaps I didn't make myself clear enough when describing the problem? Tell me if not and I will try to do better, thank you.

Comment: Anything referencing your variable game_data needs to be within your loop. So all that after game_data = r.json() needs to be indented.

Comment: @chitown88 so everytime i initiate a new loop i need to make an intendation?

Comment: Well depends. But yes. For loops will be indented. If you want a nested for loops, you’ll have indentation within indentation (if that makes sense). I’m not near a computer now, but will be later tonight to show you. But the problem you’re having is with the indentation of your for loops...they need be included in your initial for loop.

Comment: @chitown88 It kinda makes sense, but I have been raising I few errors trying to get it right! Appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: This code should actually fail with a syntax error because of missing indentation after a for-loop.

Comment: @MichaelButscher it has atleast failed me on doing it’s task, I’m suprised that I haven’t gotten a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the indents to include what you needed within your initial for loop.See if this fixes your issue:

```
#Importing Libraries 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

#Create Empty lists
player_id = {}
goalie_id = {}

person = []
position = []
skaterstats = []

goalie_person=[]
goalie_position=[]
goalie_stats=[]

team = []
team_goals = []
matchid = []

#Connect to NHL-API
for game_id in range(2017020001, 2017020100, 1):
    url = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/game/{}/feed/live'.format(game_id)
    r = requests.get(url)
    game_data = r.json()

    #Get Keys for Players/Goalies
    for homeaway in ['home','away']:
        player_dict = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('skaters')
        player_id[homeaway] = player_dict

    for homeaway in ['home','away']:
        goalie_dict = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('goalies')
        goalie_id[homeaway] = goalie_dict 

    #Get PlayerStats/TeamStats
    for homeaway in player_id:
        for playerID in player_id[homeaway]:
            play_dict_teamname = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
            play_dict_teamgoals = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('teamStats').get('teamSkaterStats').get('goals')                
            play_dict_gameid = game_data.get('gamePk')

            play_dict_person = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('person')
            play_dict_position = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('position')
            play_dict_skaterstats = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(playerID)).get('stats').get('skaterStats')

             #Append TeamStats to Empty list
            team.append(play_dict_teamname)
            team_goals.append(play_dict_teamgoals)
            matchid.append(play_dict_gameid)

            #Append PlayerStats to Empty list
            person.append(play_dict_person)
            position.append(play_dict_position)
            if play_dict_skaterstats: 
                skaterstats.append(play_dict_skaterstats)
            if not play_dict_skaterstats:
                play_dict_skaterstats = {}
                play_dict_skaterstats['timeOnIce'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['assists'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['goals'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['shots'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['hits'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['powerPlayGoals'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['powerPlayAssists'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['penaltyMinutes'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['faceOffPct'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['faceOffWins'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['faceoffTaken'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['takeaways'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['giveaways'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['shortHandedGoals'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['shortHandedAssists'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['blocked'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['plusMinus'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['evenTimeOnIce'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['powerPlayTimeOnIce'] = None
                play_dict_skaterstats['shortHandedTimeOnIce'] = None

    skaterstats.append(play_dict_skaterstats)

    #Get GoalieStats
    for homeaway in goalie_id:
        for goalieID in goalie_id[homeaway]:
            play_dict_teamname = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('team').get('name')
            play_dict_teamgoals = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('teamStats').get('teamSkaterStats').get('goals')                
            play_dict_gameid = game_data.get('gamePk')

            goalie_dict_person = play_dict_person = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(goalieID)).get('person')
            goalie_dict_position = play_dict_person = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(goalieID)).get('position')
            goalie_dict_stats = play_dict_person = game_data.get('liveData').get('boxscore').get('teams').get(homeaway).get('players').get('ID' + str(goalieID)).get('stats').get('goalieStats')

            #Append GoalieStats to Empty list
            goalie_person.append(goalie_dict_person)
            goalie_position.append(goalie_dict_position)
            if goalie_dict_stats: 
                goalie_stats.append(goalie_dict_stats)

            #Append TeamStats to Empty list
            team.append(play_dict_teamname)
            team_goals.append(play_dict_teamgoals)
            matchid.append(play_dict_gameid)

#Create DataFrames for all lists
df_person = pd.DataFrame(person)
df_position = pd.DataFrame(position)
df_skaterstats = pd.DataFrame(skaterstats)

df_team = pd.DataFrame(team)
df_teamgoals = pd.DataFrame(team_goals)
df_gameID = pd.DataFrame(matchid)

df_goalie_per = pd.DataFrame(goalie_person)
df_goalie_pos = pd.DataFrame(goalie_position)
df_goalie_stats = pd.DataFrame(goalie_stats)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, will give it a go immediatly!

Comment: worked perfecly, and surely a lifetime faster. Thank you!

Comment: cool. Looks like you still have a little work merging those dataframes, but hopefully this gets you on your way. Do you see what I mean though? The game_data was a separate loop. essentially wouldn't go into the next loops until it looped through your game_data, hence only getting the last game.

Comment: Nono, the rest of the code is done, been testing and coding for 12 hours on only 1 page from the API, and now when I went to get everything, that part didn’t do it’s work. So thank you again!

Comment: Nice. Looks like a cool project you’re working on. I did something similar to this with MLB and NFL data.

Comment: This is the second model I build, I just take all off it and feed it to a Neural Network to get predictions on who is going to win. The first model had game this has player data, then i'm going to ensemble them in a way I do not know how and hopefully get better accurcy! 70% right now, really fun

Comment: Haha. Similar idea here. Fed into neural net but to predict fantasy points.

Comment: My first ever project and experience with python, really grateful for this amazing community, helped me write all the hard parts! I only take credit for the bad parts of it!